# Map values of a column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe **a**

```
   user_id  client
        1       1
        2       0
        3       0
        4       0
```

I want to map the value 'client' to 1 if the user_id is present in this other dataframe, mantaining the '1' from the original dataframe in this dataframe **b**:

```
   user_id
       10
        3
        4
```

So it looks like

```
   user_id  client
        1       1
        2       0
        3       1
        4       1
```

Tried something like this but looks ugly and doesnt work:

```
a[a['client']==0]=a[a['user_id']==0].isin(b['user_id']).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution need [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select columns names:

```
m = a['client']==0
a.loc[m, 'client'] = a.loc[m, 'user_id'].isin(b['user_id']).astype(int)
print (a)
   user_id  client
0        1       1
1        2       0
2        3       1
3        4       1
```

Another idea is chain both masks by `&` for bitwise `AND` and pass to [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
m1 = a['client']==0
m2 = a['user_id'].isin(b['user_id'])

a['client'] = a['client'].mask(m1 & m2, 1)
print (a)
   user_id  client
0        1       1
1        2       0
2        3       1
3        4       1
```

Or with `DataFrame.loc`:

```
m1 = a['client']==0
m2 = a['user_id'].isin(b['user_id'])

a.loc[m1 & m2 , 'client'] = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and  [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True`:

```
In [2862]: import numpy as np

In [2863]: x = a.merge(b, how='left', indicator=True)
In [2857]: x['client'] = np.where(x._merge == 'both', 1, x.client)

In [2859]: x.drop('_merge', 1, inplace=True)

In [2860]: x
Out[2860]: 
   user_id  client
0        1       1
1        2       0
2        3       1
3        4       1
```